# Is there a way to insert multiple images into a post at the same time without using a gallery?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, images

I'm trying to find a way to add multiple images to a blog post in wordpress at the same time. I want to be able to write text above and blow the images, just like a normal blog post. It takes a lot of time to add each image one at a time (especially if there are like 50 or so images in a post.)

I can do a gallery, but that doesn't allow you to write content above and below.

Any ideas on how I can do something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plug in which lets you do just this very things. It works great!

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faster-image-insert/

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way and I dont think thats possible, but why not just use a wordpress gallery that gives you the option to have captions below the images?

Comment: I don't want to just add captions. I want to insert them in the content area. I actually found a way to to this. See answer.